# Can these matrices be multiplied in $\mathcal O(n^2)$ time?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Consider a real-valued orthogonal matrix $Q$ and a sequence of diagonal matrices $\{D_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$. All entries of $Q$ are real and the entries of each $D_n$ are real and positive. What is the cost of the following multiplication(s)?

$$\Sigma_m = Q D_m Q^\top$$

Is there any way this can be accomplished in $\mathcal O(n^2)$ time? I'm interested in the *amortized cost*, meaning that I'm okay with a $\mathcal O(n^3)$ pre-processing step if it leads to (eventual) $\mathcal O(n^2)$ multiplications.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but there are fast algorithms to multiply a matrix with its transpose. So you could factor $D$ (ending up with complex numbers) and then compute $Q \sqrt{D}$ in $n^2$, and then the full product in time [$2/(2^\omega-3) n^\omega$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.04109.pdf).

Comment: @tch that's a very helpful observation - thank you.

Comment: What is a (stochastic) diagonal matrix? I understand that to be a matrix whose rows (or columns) sum to 1, which would imply an identity matrix.

Comment: @AlexR. I meant that the matrix is itself is a stochastic process. I forgot that row/column stochastic has a very specific meaning in matrix algebra. I have edited this out of the question as I don't think its relevant to the question. All that matters is that we don't know $D_{n+1}$ until after we have computed $\Sigma_n$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your goal with getting the original matrix? I'm just wondering if maybe you can do what you truly want without reconstructing the original matrix?

Comment: @AlexR. I'm inverting matrices of moderate size a very large number of times. Each matrix is connected and has a very specific structure which I'm trying to exploit. I can write the inverse of the original matrix as $QDQ^\top$ where $Q$ is static and can be stored in memory. So while I have avoided the need for any inversion I still need to multiply the matrices - so I haven't saved any time (at least asymptotically)

Comment: I gotcha. But curiously what are you ultimately doing with the inverted matrix? What is so important about knowing the (i,j) coefficient?

Comment: @AlexR.For evaluation of a likelihood function (in the context of MCMC).

Comment: If you're inverting(directly or via matrix product) a moderately sized matrix many times, then is the asymptotic cost of the inverse/product really that important? If I understand your setup, you would only need a single matrix product so if $n$ isn't too big that seems okay to pay $n^3$. How do you compute the sum of the $D_i$s if there are an infinite number? Also, your notation double uses $n$ now.

Comment: @tch that was sloppy notation on my part. The matrices are $n\times n$. I have changed the other index to $m$ indicating that I need $m=1,2,\cdots, M$ inversions. You're right that I don't *really* care about *asymptotic* savings, but I do care about practical time savings. Was just hoping that it could be done in quadratic time. I'm realizing that it's not possible in general.

Comment: @tch Your comment has helped me reduce the runtime by a factor of roughly $2$. If you would like to post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Maybe add that a quadratic algorithm doesn't seem possible (if you agree) for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any algorithm for this, although perhaps someone knows of one. Nothing I write below uses the fact that $Q$ is orthogonal, so perhaps that can be exploited in some way.

In terms of theoretical asymptotic complexity, $AA^T$ can be computed slightly faster than an arbitrary matrix product can be. Specifically, faster by a factor [$2/(2^\omega-3)$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.04109.pdf) where $\omega$ is currently about 2.37.

However, since your matrices are of size $n=1000$, the constants suppressed by the big-O, and more importantly, the implementation of the matrix product algorithms will come into play. Effectively using a library such as numpy which takes advantage e of CPU caching, factorization, etc. will likely have a very large impact on the runtime.

### symmetry

If we're assuming we are going to pay $n^3$, then we should focus on the constant in front. An obvious optimization is that $QD_mQ^T$ is symmetric, so only the upper (or lower) triangular part needs to be computed.
This can be done directly bu noting that,
$$
[\Sigma_m]_{i,j} 
= Q_{[:,i]}^T D_m Q_{[:,j]}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} [D_m]_{k,k} Q_{i,k} Q_{k,j}
$$
where $Q_{[:,j]}$ is the $j$-th column of $Q$.
Naively computing $\Sigma_m$ this way would require $3n-1$ flops, and need to be done for $n(n+1)/2$ entries.
If $m=1,\ldots, M$, then this is a total cost of $M(3n-1)n(n+1)/2\approx (3/2)Mn^3$.

### preprocessing

However, notice that the only dependence of this sum on $D_m$ is the term $[D_{m}]_{k,k}$.
Thus, the product $Q_{i,k}Q_{k,j}$ can be precomputed. If we define a new vector
$$
q^{(i,j)} = [Q_{i,1}Q_{1,j}, Q_{i,2}Q_{2,j}, \ldots, Q_{i,n}Q_{n,j} ]^T
$$
then we have $[\Sigma_{m}]_{i,j} = (q^{(i,j)})^T d_m$, where $d_m$ is the vector with entries equal to those of the diagonal of $D_m$.

By symmetry, $q^{(i,j)} = q^{(j,i)}$, so we can preprocess our data set by computing $q^{(i,j)}$, $i=1,2,\ldots, n$, $j=1,2,\ldots, i$, and storing the $n(n+1)/2$ many vectors. The cost of computing each $q^{(i,j)}$ is $n$, so the total cost is $n^2(n+1)/2 \approx n^3/2$ (also this much storage is required).

### vectorization

Now the cost of computing $[\Sigma_{m}]_{i,j}$ is the cost of a dot product: $2n-1$ which must be done $n(n+1)/2$ times for each $\Sigma_m$.
This gives a total cost of $n^2(n+1)/2 + M(2n-1)n(n+1)/2 \approx n^3/2 + M n^3$, so if $M$ is very large we improve by a factor of roughly 1.5.

But, perhaps even more important is that all of these products can be vectorized.
Specifically, we can store the $q^{(i,j)}$s in a $n(n+1)/2\times n$ matrix, and all the $d_m$s in a $n\times M$ matrix. The last step would be to take the data out of this matrix product and put it into a useable form.

What is faster in practice will probably depend a lot on what libraries you're able to use, and how they manage memory, etc.

Comment: Great answer - thanks. Unfortunately, I can't use vectorization because the matrix $D_{m+1}$ isn't given until after we have "evaluated" the product at time $m$.